# Using SQL to print data from two different tables but using a third table as a link between the two

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, inner-join

[image: Image attatched to show what the outcome should be and how the tables are related]

I have 3 Tables. EMPLOYEES, LOCATIONS and DEPARTMENTS.

I need to write a SQL statement to display the first_name from EMPLOYEES and the city they live in.

The way that is linked though works like this:

- Each employee has an Employee_ID which is found in the EMPLOYEES table and the DEPARTMENTS table
- The DEPARTMENTS table has a Location_ID which is also present in the LOCATIONS Table.

I will add a picture to explain it better, but I dont know how the statement should look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sampled data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join:

```
select e.first_name, l.city
from employees e
inner join departments d on d.employee_id = e.employee_id
inner join locations l on l.location_id = d.location_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You said it all, just **join** those tables. Sample data first; query you need begins at line #18.

```
SQL> with
  2  employees (first_name, employee_id) as
  3    (select 'Jack', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'Jill', 2 from dual union all
  5     select 'Paul', 3 from dual
  6    ),
  7  departments (employee_id, location_id) as
  8    (select 1, 10 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 20 from dual union all
 10     select 3, 30 from dual
 11    ),
 12  locations (location_id, city) as
 13    (select 10, 'Narnia'   from dual union all
 14     select 20, 'Valhalla' from dual union all
 15     select 30, 'Atlantis' from dual
 16    )
 17  --
 18  select e.first_name, l.city
 19  from employees e join departments d on e.employee_id = d.employee_id
 20  join locations l on l.location_id = d.location_id
 21  order by e.employee_id;

FIRS CITY
---- --------
Jack Narnia
Jill Valhalla
Paul Atlantis

SQL>
```